# What are the correct link options to use std::thread in GCC under linux?

Tags: c++, multithreading, g++, c++11

Hi I am trying to use `std::thread` with G++. Here is my test code

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char **){
    std::thread tt([](){ std::cout<<"Thread!"<<std::endl; });
    tt.join();
}
```

It compiles, but when I try to run it the result is:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Operation not permitted 
Aborted
```

My compiler version:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

What is wrong with my test code?

UPDATE: I use the following command line to compile and run my code.

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp
$ ./a.out
```

and I tried

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x -lpthread test.cpp
$ ./a.out
```

still the same.

Comment: @Earth Engine: this SO answer explains why there are no link errors without the pthread library: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6266345/12711  Short answer: `glibc` has do-nothing stubs for many pthread functions.

Comment: @EarthEngine can you please put the solution in an answer? Specifically that the `-lpthread` must *follow* the source file.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I think on Linux pthread is used to implement `std::thread` so you need to specify the `-pthread` compiler option.

As this is a linking option, this compiler option need to be **AFTER** the source files:

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp -pthread
```

Comment: I am trying to compile a very simple program using gcc 4.7.1 and I am having the very same "operation not permitted" error. The problem is that I'm already using -pthread flag. Is there any other flag you know about?

Comment: I resolved the problem removing the "-static" flag from linker options, don't know why this happens

Comment: I am wondering why the compiler doesn't give an error when compiling without the -lpthread option. Anybody??

Comment: I tried the compiler option `-pthread` first, and this didn't fix the problem. Once I added `-lpthread` also, it worked (but I didn't try `-lpthread` by itself)

Comment: Under Ubuntu 14.04 g++ --version (g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1)
I had to add the -W1, --no-as-needed 
g++ --std=c++11 -Wl, --no-as-needed -pthread main.cc

Comment: `-Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive` resolves the problem, not `-pthread`. This is link issue [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52590) According to `man gcc` `-pthread` is just g++ options that adds multithreading support that sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker

Answer (score 6):

In addition to using `-std=c++0x` and `-pthread` you must **not** use `-static`.

Answer (score 5):

`-std=c++11 -static -pthread -Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive` works together with `-static`!!!

See here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52590#c4

Comment: It gets super bulky with `--whole-archive`. I found that [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27774767/673826) for static linking works for me on OpenWRT

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple CMake file for compiling a C++11 program that uses threads:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
list(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-pthread -std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
add_executable(main main.cpp)
```

One way of building it is:

```
mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake .. && make
```

Comment: Your solution is no improvement over hmjd's answer for me and adds unnessary stuff (profiling, test-coverage)

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling this way in single command:

```
g++ your_prog.cpp -o your_output_binary -lpthread -std=gnu++11
```

You can also try C++11 instead of gnu++11. Hope this works.