# how to configure a c++ source build for c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to make and install [MGSim simulator](http://dist.svp-home.org/deploy/mgsim-3.5.41-3724f.tar.bz2) from source code. To do that I entered the following configuration command:
`[root@dhcppc2 build-mtalpha]# ../configure --target=mtalpha --disable-trace-checks --prefix=/home/mehdi/mgsim CXX=g++ CPPFLAGS=-std=c++0x`

I think I have enabled C++11 support by providing `c++0x' flag, but I still get the following error:

`configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++11 language features is required.`

I entered other alternatives for c++0x such as c++11, g++, gnu-0x, etc. but none worked.
The full configure output is [here](http://pastebin.com/ZsKp6eXb):

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... mtalpha-unknown-none
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for a Python interpreter with version >= 2.6... python
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
checking for python version... 2.7
checking for python platform... linux2
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.7/site-packages
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
checking for help2man... no
checking for rst2man... no
checking for rst2man.py... no
checking for tbl... tbl
checking for groff... groff
checking for ps2pdf... ps2pdf
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking whether the compiler supports GCC C++ ABI name demangling... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++11 supports range-based for loops... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++11 supports auto and decltype declarations... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++11 supports double right angle brackets in template uses (a<b<int>>)... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++11 supports initializer lists... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++11 supports static_assert... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++11 supports constructor reuse... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++11 supports move references... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++11 supports std::array... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++11 supports threads... no
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++0x supports range-based for loops... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++0x supports auto and decltype declarations... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++0x supports double right angle brackets in template uses (a<b<int>>)... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++0x supports initializer lists... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++0x supports static_assert... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++0x supports constructor reuse... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++0x supports move references... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++0x supports std::array... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++0x supports threads... no
checking whether g++ -std=c++11 supports range-based for loops... yes
checking whether g++ -std=c++11 supports auto and decltype declarations... yes
checking whether g++ -std=c++11 supports double right angle brackets in template uses (a<b<int>>)... yes
checking whether g++ -std=c++11 supports initializer lists... yes
checking whether g++ -std=c++11 supports static_assert... yes
checking whether g++ -std=c++11 supports constructor reuse... yes
checking whether g++ -std=c++11 supports move references... yes
checking whether g++ -std=c++11 supports std::array... yes
checking whether g++ -std=c++11 supports threads... no
checking whether g++ -std=c++0x supports range-based for loops... yes
checking whether g++ -std=c++0x supports auto and decltype declarations... yes
checking whether g++ -std=c++0x supports double right angle brackets in template uses (a<b<int>>)... yes
checking whether g++ -std=c++0x supports initializer lists... yes
checking whether g++ -std=c++0x supports static_assert... yes
checking whether g++ -std=c++0x supports constructor reuse... yes
checking whether g++ -std=c++0x supports move references... yes
checking whether g++ -std=c++0x supports std::array... yes
checking whether g++ -std=c++0x supports threads... no
configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++11 language features is required.
```

The full configure log can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/Z4GMxpu6).

Comment: Maybe your compiler doesn't support the feature the source code requires.  Hard to tell, you didn't include your compiler version.  Or, you know, you could look at the *message right before the error* which says `checking whether g++ -std=c++0x supports threads... no`.  Try enabling threading support?

Comment: What is your g++ version? The problem might be that it is too old.

Comment: And definitely, include **full** output of the `configure` script. As usual, the actual problem is probably shown a couple of lines before the final "error" line.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `CXXFLAGS`, not `CPPFLAGS` (see https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.65/html_node/Preset-Output-Variables.html). And maybe you need full-on `-std=c++11` to support the required features?

Comment: @JanHudec g++ reports version 5.1.1. I also included configure log in the post.

Comment: @mindriot, placing CXXFLAGS instead of CPPFLAGS also didn't help.

Comment: I think the answer by @Yakk is on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The configure script mentions a lack of thread support on the line right before the error.  I doubt this is a coincidence.

A quick google finds a SO post [that says this is how you enable threading support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8649908/1774667): `-pthread`.

Comment: Thank you. `../configure --target=mtalpha --disable-trace-checks --prefix=/home/mehdi/mgsim CXX=g++ CXXFLAGS=-pthread` finally solved the issue.

Comment: It is, however, strange autoconf does not know threading requires `-pthread`…

Comment: Furthermore, `CPPFLAGS=-std=c++0x` is a no-op.