# std::call_once throws std::system_error (Unknown error -1)

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I was using the C++ OpenCL wrapper and I was wondering why my program crashed. I discovered any call to `std::call_once` was throwing an error.

```
#include <mutex>

int main() {
    static std::once_flag f;
    std::call_once(f, []{});
}
```

Program output:

> ```
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
>   what():  Unknown error -1
> ```

Here's the output of `g++ -v`:

> ```
> Using built-in specs.
> COLLECT_GCC=g++
> COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.1/lto-wrapper
> Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
> Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-libmpx --with-system-zlib --with-isl --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libssp --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-install-libiberty --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp
> Thread model: posix
> gcc version 8.1.1 20180531 (GCC)
> ```

Comment: Do you have `-pthread` in your `CXX_FLAGS`?

Comment: No. It is required for it to work I suppose?

Comment: Yes, since the underlying implementation uses pthreads, you need to pass that flag to g++. Among other things, it'll link your program to `libpthread`.

Comment: @Praetorian wow it actually worked! Thank you. If you wish to post it as an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: I didn't post an answer because I don't want to dig up docs on why `-pthread` helps :) You can post an answer yourself if you want to.

Comment: [Dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44653808/3002139), but your Q is better.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As said in the comments by Praetorian, `std::call_once` need to call the system threading library. More specifically, it will call `__gthread_once`. If the executable is not linked to pthread, that function will return `-1` and will then cause the exception to be thrown.

To make a program pthread-enabled `-pthread` option needs to be passed both to compiler and linker, as stated in [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-pthread-1). Just linking with `-lpthread` sometimes [is not enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling) and [not just because of additional macros](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.programming.threads/NCEpG0EOCCY). For CMake users there is an out of the box module that can help adding support for pthread (or any system threading library) that can be used like that:

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(myTarget PRIVATE Threads::Threads)
```

This will add any required compile and link flags if necessary.