# C++ date library fails with timezone

Tags: c++, date, c++20

This used to play once. I am trying to get some data from the C++ [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library but an exception is caught. I am compiling with

> -DUSE_AUTOLOAD=0 -DHAS_REMOTE_API=0 -DUSE_OS_TZDB=1

what is wrong with the code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <exception>

using namespace date;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    try {

    auto current_time_zone = make_zoned("Europe/Athens", std::chrono::system_clock::now());

    auto current_day = date::format("%A", current_time_zone);
    auto current_time = date::format("%H:%M", current_time_zone);

    std::cout << "day: " << current_day << ", time: " << current_time << " in timezone: " << current_time_zone << std::endl;
    //std::cout << " in timezone: " << current_time_zone << std::endl;

    } catch ( std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;

    }

}
```

Comment: I've just added the tag c++20, making this question on topic.  The library the OP references is an example implementation of the C++20 draft specification.

Comment: What is the message in the `.what()`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: "*I'm curious what is the evidence that "the date library" being "quite popular".*" I don't know if it is genuinely "quite popular", but I think it being *voted into the standard library* for C++20 will improve its popularity ;) For those who keep abreast of C++ developments, it is known. Though the OP did not make it clear enough what he was talking about for those who have never heard of it.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Unknown error -1

Comment: @cateof:  I'm not positive what the problem is, but I can tell you that my lib doesn't throw an exception that contains the message "Unknown error".  Try adding `-DONLY_C_LOCALE=1` to your build flags.  This will avoid your std::lib's `time_put` facet, but will limit you to only the "C" locale.  If this fixes the problem, then it is your std::lib's  `std::time_put` facet that threw the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `-pthread` flag. `tz.cpp` uses `call_once` to do part of the initialisation. And without `-pthread` it's not going to work (as underneath it need something like `__gthread_once`). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584960/stdcall-once-throws-stdsystem-error-unknown-error-1) for more details.

You can verify if that's the problem by running your example with `gdb` (use the `catch throw`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive what the problem is, but I can tell you that [this library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) does not throw an exception that contains the message "Unknown error".

Try adding `-DONLY_C_LOCALE=1` to your build flags. This will avoid your std::lib's `time_put` facet, but will limit you to only the "C" locale. If this fixes the problem, then it is your std::lib's `std::time_put` facet that threw the exception.