# Wrap and execute packaged_task inside lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, future, packaged-task

I'm trying to wrap a packaged_task in a lambda in order to stock them inside a container. I wrote a test code below for simulating the wrapping and calling the lambda function. My code is as follows:

```
int test()
{
    return 10;
}

int main()
{
    auto task = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<int()>>(test);
    auto result = task->get_future();
    auto wrapper = [=]() { (*task)(); };
    wrapper();
}
```

The program got aborted with the following exception:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
what():  Unknown error -1
Aborted (core dumped)

Could someone explain me why the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::packaged_task::operator()` indirectly uses `std::call_once`, which, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584960/stdcall-once-throws-stdsystem-error-unknown-error-1) link, requires pthread library to operate, otherwise it throws `std::system_error`. So to get rid of this exception, you need to build with `-lpthread`. Sounds weird, but worked for me.

Comment: Yes it is working by adding -lpthread to my gcc command. Thank you very much!