# Protobuf ShortDebugString() crash

Tags: c++, debugging, protocol-buffers, proto3

I have the following proto:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
package pb;

message FooBar {
  string foo = 1;
  string bar = 2;
}

message FooBarList {
  repeated FooBar foobar = 1;
}
```

I just populate the repeated list with 2 values and try to print it as bellow:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "foobar.pb.h"

int main()
{
    pb::FooBarList foobar_list;

    auto foobar1 = foobar_list.add_foobar();
    foobar1->set_foo("foo1");
    foobar1->set_bar("bar1");

    auto foobar2 = foobar_list.add_foobar();
    foobar2->set_foo("foo2");
    foobar2->set_bar("bar2");

    try {
        std::cout << foobar_list.ShortDebugString() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This generates the following output:

```
error: Unknown error -1
```

So, `ShortDebugString()` triggers an exception down the line which does not have any meaningful information.
Am I doing something wrong, or do I need somehow to trigger the serialization before calling `ShortDebugString()`?

Here is the gdb `callstack` if I let the exeption propagate:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7add355 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7add355 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7ac6853 in abort () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7e5d86a in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler () at /build/gcc/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:95
#3  0x00007ffff7e69d8a in __cxxabiv1::__terminate (handler=<optimized out>) at /build/gcc/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:48
#4  0x00007ffff7e69df7 in std::terminate () at /build/gcc/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:58
#5  0x00007ffff7e6a09e in __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=obj@entry=0x5555556e1550, 
    tinfo=tinfo@entry=0x7ffff7f97590 <typeinfo for std::system_error>, dest=dest@entry=0x7ffff7e96860 <std::system_error::~system_error()>)
    at /build/gcc/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:95
#6  0x00007ffff7e609bc in std::__throw_system_error (__i=-1)
    at /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/new_allocator.h:89
#7  0x00005555555a1018 in google::protobuf::internal::AssignDescriptors(google::protobuf::internal::DescriptorTable const*, bool) ()
#8  0x000055555556e77f in pb::FooBarList::GetMetadataStatic() ()
#9  0x000055555556ceb9 in pb::FooBarList::GetMetadata() const ()
#10 0x00005555555d1fb4 in google::protobuf::TextFormat::Printer::Print(google::protobuf::Message const&, google::protobuf::TextFormat::Printer::TextGenerator*) const ()
#11 0x00005555555d3ef9 in google::protobuf::Message::ShortDebugString[abi:cxx11]() const ()
#12 0x00005555555705ac in main ()
(gdb)
```

---

**EDIT**

Here is the `CMakeLists.txt` used to build this project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(proto-foobar)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

set(Protobuf_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
find_package(Protobuf MODULE REQUIRED)

set(PROTO_DEFINITIONS_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/protos")
set(PROTO_DEFINITIONS "${PROTO_DEFINITIONS_PATH}/*.proto")
set(PROTO_OUTPUT_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/source")
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${PROTO_OUTPUT_PATH})

set(PROTO_HEADERS "${PROTO_OUTPUT_PATH}/foobar.pb.h")
set(PROTO_SOURCES "${PROTO_OUTPUT_PATH}/foobar.pb.cc")

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${PROTO_HEADERS} ${PROTO_SOURCES}
                   COMMAND ${PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE}
                   ARGS --cpp_out=${PROTO_OUTPUT_PATH} 
                        --proto_path=${PROTO_DEFINITIONS_PATH} 
                        ${PROTO_DEFINITIONS}
                   DEPENDS ${PROTO_DEFINITIONS}
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
                   COMMENT "Compiling ${PROJECT_NAME} protos")    

file(GLOB_RECURSE PROJECT_FILES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/source/*.cpp")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROTO_SOURCES} ${PROJECT_FILES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}       PUBLIC ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}  PUBLIC ${PROTO_OUTPUT_PATH})
```

Here is the project tree:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── protos
│   └── foobar.proto
└── source
    ├── foobar.pb.cc
    ├── foobar.pb.h
    └── main.cpp
```

Comment: Working fine. Output: `foobar { foo: "foo1" bar: "bar1" } foobar { foo: "foo2" bar: "bar2" }`. How did you compile? Command?

Comment: @Azeem, I added more details to the question.

Comment: Have you tested it other than CMake?

Comment: @Azeem, This example project in particular, no. The thing is that I use kind of the same `cmake`  in some other project and it works fine. I did this example initially to showcase some other issue, but then I got this when I was trying to print for debugging.

Comment: Right. You can test this without cmake to see if that works. There might be some configuration issue, in this case. Otherwise, the issue might be of the runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Had the exact same issue and dug into it a bit.)*

The trigger in this case is [this piece of code](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/c0b79c5a398f4eec51ef92784e9d940febdccc52/src/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.cc#L2485). It contains (indirectly) a call to [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once), which on Linux is implemented using `pthread_once`. That, in turn, requires that your binary is linked against the `pthread` library (i.e. it requires an `-lpthread` linker flag).

If your binary has not been linked against `pthread` you get the error you saw, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51584960/507519) along with a recipe for fixing this.

Comment: Thanks! In addition to the `-lpthread`, I also needed the `-pthread` flag to fix my crash.
More details also here: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/4958

  (Note: I was using protobuf 3.9.2 and gcc 9.3.0)