# ANTLR4 C++ Generated lexer not accepting input stream

Tags: c++, parsing, c++17, antlr, antlr4

I am using Ubuntu.

I am including the parser and lexer ANTLR4 generates when I use the -Dlanguage=Cpp flag. I did not change the files at all and I have taken this code from the docs.

This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "antlr4-runtime.h"
#include "ExprLexer.h"
#include "ExprParser.h"

using namespace antlr4;

int main(int , const char **) {
  // make input stream with string, put input stream into ANTLRInputStream
  ANTLRInputStream input("h");
  ExprLexer lexer(&input);
  return 0;
}
```

This is my compile statement:

```
g++ -std=c++17 *.cpp -o index -I/usr/local/include/antlr4-runtime -L. -lantlr4-runtime
```

I am using gcc g++, c++17. It compiles fine, but when I run it I get an error.

This is the error I get.

```bash
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error -1
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I suspect it is coming from an InputStream error.

I tried wrapping in try catch statements but all that told me was that it was maybe a syscall error. I am not sure how to fix that if it is true.

Comment: `I suspect` Don't suspect, start up a debugger and figure out who exactly throws this exception and why.

Comment: Debugger? Where do I find one? Is there a gnu one already installed on ubuntu?

Comment: `gdb` is a well-known debugger on GNU/linux.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I looked up a tutorial

Comment: I have not been able to fix it yet and either I don't know how to use gbd properly or it can't provide any useful information about the bug. I asked because I feel like more people might have run into this before? This is the code from the docs.

Comment: I'd just let the app `run`, GDB should break on the unhandled exception. Look at the backtrace, walk `up` the stack and chech whether all variables have the expected values.

Comment: `g++ --version`?

Comment: @kaby76 9.4.0, c++17

Comment: The problem is that `-pthread` must be used in the compilation. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51584960/4779853. When I compile my driver without the flag, it fails. Try `g++ -std=c++17 \`find . -name '*.cpp'\` -pthread -g -o xxx -I src/`, then run the executable. (I recursively copied the Cpp runtime `src/` to the directory containing the driver.)

Comment: @kaby76 Thank you! It worked! How do I add this as an answer?

Comment: Man i wasted a month on this error, not being able to find the solution anywhere! Thank you so much @kaby76 and thank you Amukh1 for filing this issue!

Comment: hey Sorry but this didn't work, It initially ran upto a point and still throws the same error sadly!

Comment: Upto what point? Where does it break? @NamanBGor

Comment: Hey! So I filed an issue at [Github](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/4499) for this