# what's the difference between pthread in /lib64/libc.so.6 with /usr/lib/libpthread.a?

Tags: c++, pthreads

what's the difference between pthread in /lib64/libc.so.6 with /usr/lib64/libpthread.a?

if I using pthread, if I should add -lpthread when linking ?

I noticed that gcc will auto add -llibc when linking, if so, I think there is no need to add -lpthread ! am I right for this understand?

[image]

Comment: that is `libpthread.a` not `libpthread.so`

Comment: No need to show console output with a printscreen. Please copy the text and format it using ctrl-k or the "code format" button in the editor.

Comment: both /usr/lib64/libpthread.so and /usr/lib64/libpthread.a existed

Answer (score 0):

See this SO question: [Does linking an `-lpthread` changes application behaviour? (Linux, Glibc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266183/does-linking-an-lpthread-changes-application-behaviour-linux-glibc)

The pthreads functions in glibc are stubs, provided to make it easier to write code that can operate in threaded or non threaded environments. They do not actually do anything.

If you actually want to use pthreads then you do need to link with -lpthread.

Comment: but why getpid() and pthread_self() can return right value if the pthread in glibc only provide stubs?

Comment: but why getpid() and pthread_self() without added link -lpthread can return right value if the pthread in glibc only provide stubs

Comment: The stubs are written to return values meaningful in a non threaded  environment. However if you tried to eg. Create a thread, you would find that you cannot. More info here http://www.ohloh.net/p/libpthread-stubs

Comment: is it weak reference?

Comment: @jiafu - yes they are weak symbols, otherwise you would not be able to link the real pthread lib

Comment: Sorry - have to correct myself. The main factor is symbol interposition. See my answer to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21103255/1411457